# How to use the regex module in python to split a string of text into the words only?

Tags: python, regex, split, expression

Here's what I'm working with…

```
string1 = "Dog,cat,mouse,bird. Human."

def string_count(text):
    text = re.split('\W+', text)
    count = 0
    for x in text:
        count += 1
        print count
        print x

return text

print string_count(string1)
```

…and here's the output…

```
1
Dog
2
cat
3
mouse
4
bird
5
Human
6

['Dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'bird', 'Human', '']
```

Why am I getting a 6 even though there are only 5 words? I can't seem to get rid of the `''` (empty string)! It's driving me insane.

Comment: In the question editor, drag-select your code and press the `{}` button located above the text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because while it splits based on the last dot, it gives the last empty part also.

You splitted the input string based on `\W+` which means split the input string based on one or more non-word character. So your regex matches the last dot also  and splits the input  based on the last dot also. Because of no string present after to the last dot, it returns an empty string  after splitting.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The string ends with a character that matches `\W+` - namely, a period (`.`).  That means there is an extra, empty field at the end of the string.  If the string began with a non-word character, there would be an empty field at the beginning, too.

Comment: Note the first example here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split demonstrates precisely this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Avinash Raj correctly stated WHY it's doing that. Here's how to fix it:

```
string1 = "Dog,cat,mouse,bird. Human."
the_list = [word for word in re.split('\W+', string1) if word]
# include the word in the list if it's not the empty string
```

Or alternatively (and this is better...)

```
string1 = "Dog,cat,mouse,bird. Human."
the_list = re.findall('\w+', string1)
# find all words in string1
```